# Sparql: split authors and editors

Tags: sparql, jena

End point

```
http://128.250.202.125:7001/joseki/
```

Query so far

```
PREFIX dc:    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX fn:    <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX ouext: <http://oracle.com/semtech/jena-adaptor/ext/user-def-function#>
PREFIX oext:  <http://oracle.com/semtech/jena-adaptor/ext/function#>
PREFIX ORACLE_SEM_FS_NS: <http://oracle.com/semtech#timeout=10,qid=12345,STRICT_DEFAULT=F,GRAPH_MATCH_UNNAMED=T>
PREFIX fae:   <http://www.findanexpert.unimelb.edu.au/ontology/>
PREFIX vitro: <http://vitro.mannlib.cornell.edu/ns/vitro/0.7#>
PREFIX vitro-public: <http://vitro.mannlib.cornell.edu/ns/vitro/public#>
PREFIX vivo:  <http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#>
PREFIX bibo:  <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select
    (sample(?title) AS ?publication_title)
    (GROUP_CONCAT(?pubPosi ; SEPARATOR = "|") AS ?publication_position)
    (GROUP_CONCAT(?personLinkDisplay ; SEPARATOR = "|") AS ?personal_link)
where {
    <http://www.findanexpert.unimelb.edu.au/individual/person16492> vivo:authorInAuthorship ?authorship .
    ?authorship vivo:linkedInformationResource ?article .
    ?article vivo:informationResourceInAuthorship ?pubPosi .
    ?pubPosi rdfs:label ?personLabel .

    ?article rdfs:label ?title.

    OPTIONAL {
        ?pubPosi vivo:linkedAuthor ?personLink .
    }

    BIND ( IF( !bound(?personLink), "empty", STR(?personLink)) AS ?personLinkDisplay )
}
group by
    ?article
```

The partial result table in image

[image]

The result from the query above explain:

Column 1: 
"Why is it rational to believe scientific theories are true?" 
This is the publication title

Column 2:

```
www.findanexpert.....position1Y, "Y" means author. 
"1" means this author is in position 1 in this publication.
"1Y" means this is an author and in position 1.

www.findanexpert.....position2N, "N" means editor. 
"2" means this editor is in position 2 in this publication.
"2N" means this is an editor and in position 2.
```

"|" is to separate author and editor, but you can see they are mixed up. I need
to have authors in one column and editors in another column.

Column 3:
It means 
www.findanexpert.../publication74143position1Y has
www.findanexpert.../person16492 (a personal profile)

www.findanexpert.../publication74143position1N has 'empty' profile.

I am not sure how to create the expected result:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UQv41NK0U2PU1tgIeBa__4lQx16v9lKinDtV7eQzMyg/edit?pli=1#gid=0

**Update 1**:

I modify the query based on suggestion from Joshua. It is close but not quite yet

Modified query

```
PREFIX dc:    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX fn:    <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX ouext: <http://oracle.com/semtech/jena-adaptor/ext/user-def-function#>
PREFIX oext:  <http://oracle.com/semtech/jena-adaptor/ext/function#>
PREFIX ORACLE_SEM_FS_NS: <http://oracle.com/semtech#timeout=15,qid=12345,STRICT_DEFAULT=F,GRAPH_MATCH_UNNAMED=T>
PREFIX fae:   <http://www.findanexpert.unimelb.edu.au/ontology/>
PREFIX vitro: <http://vitro.mannlib.cornell.edu/ns/vitro/0.7#>
PREFIX vitro-public: <http://vitro.mannlib.cornell.edu/ns/vitro/public#>
PREFIX vivo:  <http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#>
PREFIX bibo:  <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select
    #(sample(?article) as ?article_uri)
    (sample(?title) as ?the_title)

    (group_concat(distinct ?author_posi_uri ; separator='|' ) as ?authors)
  (group_concat(distinct ?the_author_link ; separator='|' ) as ?the_author_links)

  (group_concat(distinct ?editor_posi_uri ; separator='|' ) as ?editors)
  (group_concat(distinct ?the_editor_link ; separator='|' ) as ?the_editor_links)

where { 
    <http://www.findanexpert.unimelb.edu.au/individual/person16492> vivo:authorInAuthorship ?authorship .
    ?authorship vivo:linkedInformationResource ?article .
    ?article rdfs:label ?title.

    # Get authors
    # I can say an ?article should have at least one author.
  ?article vivo:informationResourceInAuthorship ?author_posi_uri .
  filter strends( str(?author_posi_uri), 'Y' ) .

  optional {
    ?author_posi_uri vivo:linkedAuthor ?author_link .
    }
  BIND ( IF( !bound(?author_link), "empty", STR(?author_link)) AS ?the_author_link ) .


  # NOTE: I was hoping to get similar result as 'get authors' above, but it is not.
  # Get editors
  # Not all ?article has editor, that is why I use first 'optional' below.
  # If there is an editor, he/she may not have editor_link (i.e. don't have a profile),
  # So I use 'optional' within another 'optional'
  optional {
    ?article vivo:informationResourceInAuthorship ?editor_posi_uri .
    filter strends( str(?editor_posi_uri), 'N' ) .

    optional {
        ?editor_posi_uri vivo:linkedAuthor ?editor_link .   
    }
    BIND ( IF( !bound(?editor_link), "empty", STR(?editor_link)) AS ?the_editor_link ) .
  }


}
group by ?article ?title
```

**Output is**

[image]

Image explained:

Column 1: 
it is the title of publication

Column 2:
authors

Column 3:
author linked profiles

Column 4:
editors

Column 5:
editor linked profiles. Column 5 is not working as I expect. I expect something similar to column 3.

**Update 2**

The image below indicates that there are 3 authors, but only 2 items show up in 'the_author_links' column, because the`'distinct'` keyword actually remove any duplicated 'empty'

```
the'distinct' keyword is collided with this
BIND ( IF( !bound(?author_link), "empty", STR(?author_link)) AS ?the_author_link )
```

[image]

Is it a way to resolve this?

Comment: We don't have access to your data.  Are you asking, instead of binding all author roles to pubPosi, how to bind values of the property to one variable if they end with Y, and to another variable if they end in Y?  That's not too hard.  Note, though, that the order you get with GROUP_CONCAT is not guaranteed to be the same, so you might have data: author1/link1, author2/link2, but end up with the concatenations authors: "author1 author2" links: "link2 link1".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, see my update above.

Comment: What happens if you move that last `BIND( ... AS ?the_editor_link )` outside the nested OPTIONAL blocks? I.e., have structure like `optional { ... optional { ... } } BIND ( ... AS ?the_editor_link )`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, column 5 is always outputting 'empty'.

Comment: We don't have access to any of your data, so we can't know what the query should return for your data.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, so you cannot access http://128.250.202.125:7001/joseki/ ?

Comment: I can access it now, but I couldn't when I tried before. Even so, questions are supposed to contain enough information to be standalone, and problems should be reproducible.  Will that endpoint remain available forever with exactly the same data so that future users will be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: At any rate, it doesn't look like any of your editors have the specified links.  E.g., the query `SELECT * WHERE  { ?x vivo:informationResourceInAuthorship ?y filter strends( str(?y), 'N' ) ?y vivo:linkedAuthor ?z }` doesn't appear to return any results.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I think you are right. I will contact the admin to confirm it

Answer (score 1):

We don't have access to your data, so we can't really help you with your exact query, but I think we can come pretty close.  Let's start with a simplified version that doesn't have authors and author links and editors and editor links, but just has a hasAuthor property, and the values of that property are URIs that end with Y or N, for authors and editors, respectively.  Then we can have some data like this:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:article2 :hasTitle "Some title" ;
          :hasAuthor :person1Y, :person2Y, :person3N, :person4N .
```

Then we can write a query that retrieves articles and their titles, and (optionally) values of the hasAuthor property.  If the value of the hasAuthor property ends with Y, then we bind it to the variable ?author, and to ?editor if it ends with N.  If it doesn't end with either of those, then we don't do anything with it.  I'll show the query and results at the end, but here's the pattern so far:

```sql
  ?article :hasTitle ?title .

  # Find "authors" with URIs ending in 'Y' (authors)
  optional { 
    ?article :hasAuthor ?author .
    filter strends( str(?author), 'Y' )
  }

  # Find "authors" with URIs ending in 'N' (editors)
  optional { 
    ?article :hasAuthor ?editor .
    filter strends( str(?editor), 'N' )
  }
```

Now, how do we put these values altogether.  First, we want to group by ?article and ?title.  Then each group has a unique ?article and ?title, and some collection of ?author and ?editor values.  We want to concatenate all distinct values of ?author, separated by |, into a variable ?authors, and similarly with ?editor into ?editors.  Thus we end up with this query and results:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?title
       (group_concat(distinct ?author ; separator='|' ) as ?authors)
       (group_concat(distinct ?editor ; separator='|' ) as ?editors)
where {
  ?article :hasAuthor :person1Y ;
           :hasTitle ?title .

  # Find "authors" with URIs ending in 'Y' (authors)
  optional { 
    ?article :hasAuthor ?author .
    filter strends( str(?author), 'Y' )
  }

  # Find "authors" with URIs ending in 'N' (editors)
  optional { 
    ?article :hasAuthor ?editor .
    filter strends( str(?editor), 'N' )
  }
}
group by ?article ?title
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| title        | authors                           | editors                           |
========================================================================================
| "Some title" | "urn:ex:person2Y|urn:ex:person1Y" | "urn:ex:person4N|urn:ex:person3N" |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, we can make the data a bit more realistic, and give the authors and editors some more information (e.g., a name).  Thus we get:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>.

:article2 :hasTitle "Some title" ;
          :hasAuthor :person1Y, :person2Y, :person3N, :person4N .

:person1Y :hasName "p1" .
:person2Y :hasName "p2" .
:person3N :hasName "p3" .
:person4N :hasName "p4" .
```

We can extend the optional blocks to grab names, too, and then add additional group concatenations:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?title
       (group_concat(distinct ?author ; separator='|' ) as ?authors)
       (group_concat(distinct ?aname  ; separator='|' ) as ?author_names)
       (group_concat(distinct ?editor ; separator='|' ) as ?editors)
       (group_concat(distinct ?ename  ; separator='|' ) as ?editor_names)
where {
  ?article :hasTitle ?title .

  # Find "authors" with URIs ending in 'Y' (authors)
  optional { 
    ?article :hasAuthor ?author .
    filter strends( str(?author), 'Y' )
    ?author :hasName ?aname .
  }

  # Find "authors" with URIs ending in 'N' (editors)
  optional { 
    ?article :hasAuthor ?editor .
    filter strends( str(?editor), 'N' )
    ?editor :hasName ?ename .
  }
}
group by ?article ?title
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| title        | authors                           | author_names | editors                           | editor_names |
======================================================================================================================
| "Some title" | "urn:ex:person2Y|urn:ex:person1Y" | "p2|p1"      | "urn:ex:person4N|urn:ex:person3N" | "p4|p3"      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now these results have authors and author names (and editors and editor names) in the same order.  You'll probably find that most SPARQL engines will have that result, but it's not actually guaranteed.  That is, you could have:

- authors: "urn:ex:person2Y|urn:ex:person1Y"
- author_names: "p1|p2"

where the order of the authors in each field is different.  Unfortuantely, there's not anything in SPARQL 1.1 that you can do to ensure that they end up in the same order. You could, I suppose, do something with string manipulation, i.e., generating a string of the form ":person1/p1|:person2/p2" and then do some replacement to get ":person1|:person2" and "p1|p2" from it.  That would preserve the order.